# Creating a table of this form in Latex

Tags: tables

I want to create a table in Latex of the following style. Also, I want to ensure that the text is aligned at the centre of columns and rows. [image]

Comment: Welcome! What did you try?

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{5mm}cccc}[hvlines,corners=NW] % NW = north-west
 & \;\diagbox{A}{B} & \Block{}{C \\ D} & \Block{}{ E \\ F} & \Block{}{ G \\ longer} \\
\Block{4-1}{H1} & I & text 1    &      & text \\
                & J & text 2    &      & text \\
                & K & text      &      & other text \\
                & L & text      &      & text \\
\Block{4-1}{H2} & M & text      & smth & text \\
                & N & text      &      & text \\
                & O & text      &      & text \\
                & P & text text &      & text \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Despite using the packages, it says `! LaTeX Error: Environment NiceTabular undefined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{NiceTabular}`

Comment: @user206089: I think you have not the latest version of the package `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation or install the latest version by hand.

Comment: Tried it on overleaf even, didn't work.

Comment: @user2060089: Overleaf is not up-to-date. Send me a mail (fpantigny@wanadoo.fr) and I will send you the most recent file 'nicematrix.sty' and all you will have to do is to upload that file in your Overleaf project.

Comment: I reinstalled MikTex on my computer, and tried running the code. I continue to get the same error.